# Return XML value after loop

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm looping around a JS function after an AJAX call for XML. When I use return it is undefined, even if I do if (i==x.length) {return}.

I would like the getInfo function to return the node values array. Which should be fairly simple, all of the code works apart from the return part.

```
var myFunction = {
sendAjax: function (url, success) {
            var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            xhr.open('POST', url);
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState > 3 && xhr.status == 200) success(xhr.responseXML);
            };
            xhr.send();
            return xhr;
        },

getInfo: function () {
            myFunction.sendAjax('XXXXXXXXX', function (data) {
                var i;
                var xmlDoc = data
                var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Session");
                var sessions = [];

                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    sessions[i] += xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("XXXX")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + ","

            console.log(sessions[i]);

          }

                    return sessions;

                });
            }
   }

myFunction.getInfo(function(value){ 
  console.log('mylog=' + value);
  alert(value);
});
```

Result comes back as undefined, it IS looping around and returning the values fine, but the return is returning before the loop is finished. I have tried doing an if statement i.e. if (i==x.length) then return ... but that does not work.

Comment: Assume that the URL etc is set and the XML is looping correct (I've checked it is). It's just the return part I'm stuck on. Also, the sendAjax function I am using for other JS functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how asynchronous functions and returns interact. Execution will continue as soon as all code in the control flow has been carried out, without waiting for async callbacks to complete. Take a look at this stripped down example:

```js
function foo(){
  setTimeout(function(){
   return 5;
  }, 500);
}

//calling foo
alert(foo());
```

Note how it alerts undefined and not 5. This is because the calling code continues executing as soon as foo() is finished running, and doesn't wait for the timeout to execute. Therefore, foo() returns nothing, and alert() alerts undefined.

The correct, callback way to write the above would be:

```js
function foo(callbackFn){
  setTimeout(function(){
   callbackFn(5);
  }, 500);
}

foo(function(value){ 
  alert(value);
});
```

Comment: Hey Deeclan, I completely unnderstand how ASYNC works, it moves onto the next part of the code. My question is how do I, in that function, return the value? I've tried when (i == x.length) {return sessions}

Comment: Ok - I understand, so ....  myFunction.getInfo(function(value){ 
  alert(value);
});

Comment: Exactly. Your call should be `myFunction.getInfo( function(sessions) { //do whatever you want with the session data... });`. Then in your getInfo declaration, include `callbackFunction` as a parameter and then do `callbackFunction(sessions);` rather than `return sessions;`.

Comment: Updated code as suggested, it is looping through correctly but the function is not returning anything. myFunction.getInfo is not even console logging. I'm probably being an idiot .....

Comment: @JPr If your updated code is what you updated in the OP, that's not finished.

`getInfo: function () {` needs to be `getInfo: function (callbackFunction) {` and 

`return sessions;` needs to be `callbackFunction(sessions);`